# $A$-module and free $A$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and consider an $A$-module $M$. Why do we always have the following exact sequence?
>   $$A^{(J)}\rightarrow A^{(I)}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$

(Here $I,J$ are sets and $A^{(I)}$, $A^{(J)}$ are free $A$-modules indexed by $I$ and $J$.)

The map $A^{(I)}\rightarrow M$ is clear: if $\{m_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a set of generators then $(a_i)\mapsto\sum a_im_i$.

But what is the map $A^{(J)}\rightarrow A^{(I)}$?

Comment: just repeat the same construction with a set of generators of $\ker (A^{(I)} \to M)$.

Comment: It represents the relations between the chosen generators of $M$ that are not induced solely by being an $A$ module. For instance, the Klein $4$-group $V$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module has $$\Bbb Z^2\to \Bbb Z^2\to V\to0$$where the second map is the obvious $(m,n)\mapsto (\bar m,\bar n)$, while the first map is multiplication by $2$, since multiplication by $2$ kills elements of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really mysterious. For every module $M$ there exists an epimorphism $g\colon A^{(I)}\to M$, for some set $I$. Consider the kernel $K$ of this epimorphism and apply the same fact, to get a homomorphism $f\colon A^{(J)}\to A^{(I)}$ having $K$ as its image. Then the sequence
$$
A^{(J)}\xrightarrow{f}A^{(I)}\xrightarrow{g}M\to 0
$$
is exact.

Just take a set of generators of $K$ (these can be seen as the relations between the generators of $M$).

Comment: In fact more is true: a *natural* choice of generators and relations is possible. For generators take every element of $M$, and for relations take every relation they satisfy...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, of course: that's even functorial!